# Centralised configuration of docker-compose services

Tags: database, docker, config, docker-compose, microservices

Imagine a non-trivial [docker compose](https://www.docker.com/docker-compose) app, with nginx in front of a webapp, and a few linked data stores:

```css
web:
  build: my-django-app
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - redis
    - mysql
    - mongodb
nginx:
  image: nginx
  links:
    - web
redis:
  image: redis
  expose:
    - "6379"
mysql:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=myproject
mongodb:
  image: mongo
```

The databases are pretty easy to configure (for now), the containers expose pretty nice environmental variables to control them (see the `mysql` container), but what of `nginx`? We'll need to template a vhost file for that, right?

I don't want to roll my own image, that'll need rebuilding for each changed config, from different **devs**' setups, to **test**, through **staging** and **production**. And what if we want to, in a lightweight manner, do **A/B testing** by flipping a config option?

Some **centralised config management** is needed here, maybe something controlled by docker-compose that can write out config files to a shared volume?

This will only get more important as new services are added (imagine a microservice cloud, rather than, as in this example, a monolithic web app)

**What is the correct way to manage configuration in a docker-compose project?**

Comment: I'm keen to keep config in envs (rationale here http://12factor.net/config), but then what of the services that you can't config easily with simple key/values, like the above nginx example?

Comment: The easiest solution is just to write an entrypoint script which populates the nginx config file with the values from the environment variables, then starts nginx. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you Adrian, that would indeed work for nginx, but what about the next one and the next one, seems odd there wouldn't be an existing solution (etcd, confd?) pattern

Comment: Or, are you saying, in your experience, is a little entrypoint.sh enough to bootstrap every container?

Comment: I expanded on my comment in an answer. I think it's enough in the vast majority of cases and certainly a common pattern.

Comment: Agreed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In general you'll find that most containers use entrypoint scripts to configure applications by populating configuration files using environment variables. For an advanced example of this approach see the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh) for the [Wordpress official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

Because this is a common pattern, Jason Wilder created the [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) project to help automate the process.